# Select number of Partitions on basis of size of File Read by Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a use case in which sometimes I received 400GB data and sometimes 1MB data. I have set number of partitions to a hard coded value let's say 300. When I receive 1MB then script makes 300 partitions of very small sizes. I want to avoid this, somehow I want to partition the dataframe on basis of size. Let's say I want to make each partition of size 2GB.

Comment: Check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61338374/how-to-calculate-size-of-dataframe-in-spark-scala/61338455#61338455 & let me know if its not help ..:)

Comment: Yes this is solving my problem by calculating size of dataframe and defined ranges that if size is m then make n number of partitions.
Thanks

Comment: Is there any direct method for this ? Like Spark build in functionality ?

Comment: its spark built in function only just we have to customise as per our need.  what output format are you using ?

Comment: I'm using parquet format

Comment: Check this config - ```spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes```.  I have't used or tested.. for more info - http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217470/discussion-between-abdul-haseeb-and-srinivas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```scala
spark.sessionState.executePlan(df.queryExecution.logical).optimizedPlan.stats.sizeInBytes
```

to get the input size. You can then convert it to GB and compute the number of partitions by dividing it single partition size (like 2 GB)

Please refer my ans for other approaches to get input size - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62463009/4758823

Comment: AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'sessionState'

Comment: above this ```spark.sessionState...``` line is for scala & for pyspark version you may need to use this - ```spark._jsparkSession.sessionState().executePlan(df._jdf.queryExecution().logical()).optimizedPlan().stats().sizeInBytes()``` & also check out spark versions .. this may not same for all spark versions..

Comment: Yes this works for me, Thanks Srinivas and Someshwar Kale